# Pure-death process -differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

[Source: Birth-death processses](https://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwjl9piG4IrTAhUMCsAKHfbmDHMQFgghMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.netlab.tkk.fi%2Fopetus%2Fs383143%2Fkalvot%2FE_bdpros.pdf&usg=AFQjCNG1dxH4xrKidFlo3m-4V1CZ-rfamw&sig2=qJ597g39fgjO_jbx097JGg)

What just happened in the last line, where the "e" came from. I am sorry if I am missing something obvious.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

The $e$ comes from solving the differential equation. Generally they appear when you see a differential equation like $$\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=kf(x)$$This happens since you can write it as
$$\frac{1}{f(x)}\frac{d}{dx}f(x)=k$$
Then integrating gives you
$$\ln(f(x)) = kx+C$$
Raising $e$ to each side, we get
$$f(x) = c* e^{kx}$$
Hope this helps!